# Load Modal Popup with ajax calls in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 application, I have been working with modal popups on various clicks with ajax.actionlinks as:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "..." }, new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
    UpdateTargetId = "new-entity",
    OnSuccess = "EntityModal",
}
```

and this works fine for me.
Also I have been using bootstrap context menus as:

```
{
    text: 'RightClickMe', href: 'javascript:test()',target: '_blank'
}
```

With this on right click on any element I will be getting one link as **RightClickMe**.Now on this click as mentioned above I am trying to call one jquery function **test()** as:

```
function test()
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Content("~/Controller/Action")",
        data: {
            //some ....
        },
        datatype : 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#new-entity").html(data);
        } 
    })
}
```

I tried with this and even lot of other found results but nothing worked for me
Here, with this function I want to load the modal popup as it loads with ajax.actionlink .

So can anyone please suggest me the way to do this i.e. I want to make some ajax calls and load the modal popups by using the script function or is there any other **alternative** to do this.I have been trying for hours and really got stuck at this point.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Reddy The desired popup are not getting rendered with this approach.The ajax loader keeps on moving and even in console it doesnot show any message.

Comment: are you using bootstrap popup?